# why with() in mice package output different results depending on the column order of data

Tags: r, r-mice

```
# Take data.frame "nhane2" for example
library(mice)
data("nhanes2")

test_im <- mice(nhanes2, m=5, seed=6666)
result1 <- pool(with(test_im, glm(chl ~ age + hyp + bmi)))
summary(result1)
#         term    estimate  std.error   statistic         df     p.value
#1 (Intercept)  13.1104206 65.8461047  0.19910700 10.1653195 0.846105234
#2    age40-59  48.2450854 21.9263645  2.20032306 12.3010743 0.047586388
#3    age60-99  67.4320383 27.9191154  2.41526414  8.2618361 0.041228191
#4      hypyes -10.7768185 24.3696204 -0.44222349  8.3354247 0.669577729
#5         bmi   5.6092711  2.3318711  2.40548077  9.3475761 0.038579657

nhanes3 <- nhanes2[, c(2, 4, 1, 3)]
test_im2 <- mice(nhanes3, m=5, seed=6666)
result2 <- pool(with(test_im2, glm(chl ~ age + hyp + bmi)))
summary(result2)
#         term  estimate  std.error  statistic        df     p.value
#1 (Intercept) 17.412538 68.5154883 0.25414017 7.9150603 0.805864761
#2    age40-59 37.548722 22.4890886 1.66964181 9.2634246 0.128369824
#3    age60-99 57.002942 26.1705631 2.17813203 8.0299934 0.060915415
#4      hypyes 10.854567 23.9251631 0.45368832 6.5794747 0.664636696
#5         bmi  5.682993  2.2596974 2.51493544 9.5803935 0.031588665
```

We could see that dataframe `nhanes2` and `nhanes3` only differ in the ordering of columns, but the results of the linear regression differ.

I think this is due to the statistically relevant sequence of operations in the mice package like `visitSequence`. I did not really understand why it happens, and I don't know how to change my code.

Comment: Can you compare the outputs of the two `mice()` calls directly?  It's likely that the random imputations for missing data are different between the two, and this would demonstrate that.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen Yes, you'r right. I use complete() to see the outputs of impuation, they are different.

Comment: I think this is a bug in `mice`,  see @Roland's answer for a possible reason. I filed an [issue at the author's github](https://github.com/amices/mice/issues/541).

Answer (score 3):

The fact that the results are different makes perfect sense, because of the way `mice` iterates over the columns sequentially. Before doing any imputations, `mice` fills in the gaps in the data with random draws from each variable, independent of all other variables. Starting from the first variable in the data (i.e., the most left column or the first column specified in the visit sequence), imputations are drawn from a prediction model, using all (or a subset) of the other variables as predictors. When imputing the second variable, the imputations for the first variable are used as predictor values, and thus the imputations for the second variable will depend on the imputations of the first variable.

If you change the order of the variables, you are inducing different values on the predictors for observations, leading to different estimated parameters in the imputation models, and thus also in different imputations.

Apart from this, there is also the randomness involved that changes the results. That is, if you draw values for the variables in a different order, you can expect different results. As an example, consider the following example in which two different distributions are used to draw values. If we change the order of the distributions but use the same seed, we will never get the same values per distribution.

```r
set.seed(123)
rnorm(5)
#> [1] -0.56047565 -0.23017749  1.55870831  0.07050839  0.12928774
rnorm(5, 5)
#> [1] 6.715065 5.460916 3.734939 4.313147 4.554338

set.seed(123)
rnorm(5, 5)
#> [1] 4.439524 4.769823 6.558708 5.070508 5.129288
rnorm(5)
#> [1]  1.7150650  0.4609162 -1.2650612 -0.6868529 -0.4456620
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Note that both factors shouldn't affect the quality of the results in the long run. That is, both approaches should yield correct inferences and nominal coverages, but the randomness involved can have consequences for the conclusions that you draw. If you want less variability between the results, you could consider increasing the number of iterations and imputations (i.e., set `m = 500` and `maxit = 100`), which reduces the Monte Carlo variation in your results. See for example the following reprex.

```r
library(mice)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'mice'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     cbind, rbind
data("nhanes2")

test_im <- mice(nhanes2, m=500, maxit = 100, seed=6666, printFlag = FALSE)
result1 <- pool(with(test_im, glm(chl ~ age + hyp + bmi)))
summary(result1)
#>          term  estimate std.error  statistic       df    p.value
#> 1 (Intercept)  7.063519 66.356797  0.1064476 12.56493 0.91690798
#> 2    age40-59 46.881649 23.099914  2.0295162 12.32924 0.06456147
#> 3    age60-99 67.064299 27.082295  2.4763152 10.84335 0.03105768
#> 4      hypyes -4.124682 23.508925 -0.1754518 11.29393 0.86383086
#> 5         bmi  5.907458  2.281963  2.5887620 12.73945 0.02278051


nhanes3 <- nhanes2[, c(2, 4, 1, 3)]
test_im2 <- mice(nhanes3, m=500, maxit = 100, seed=6666, printFlag = FALSE)
result2 <- pool(with(test_im2, glm(chl ~ age + hyp + bmi)))
summary(result2)
#>          term  estimate std.error   statistic        df    p.value
#> 1 (Intercept) 11.192876 67.984006  0.16463985 11.963859 0.87197643
#> 2    age40-59 45.322384 23.661931  1.91541360 11.693474 0.08020983
#> 3    age60-99 65.992479 27.735839  2.37932150 10.479849 0.03758996
#> 4      hypyes -2.123513 25.309925 -0.08390042  9.847869 0.93481660
#> 5         bmi  5.770442  2.330468  2.47608730 12.319292 0.02870884
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Yes, right. We can alter `visitSequence` to regulate how `mice()` jumps across the data. It would be interesting to see if we can get equivalent results in this way for different variable orders.

Comment: @StefvanBuuren It's a pity that I have tried to use `vist=test_im$vistSequence` , but it still outputs different results.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect that the order of columns interacts with the sequence in which (pseudo-) random numbers are generated within `mice`. Starting with the same random seed doesn't guarantee the same result if the random numbers are not generated in the same sequence.